# IIS reverse proxy for Jenkins with CSRF protection

Tags: iis, jenkins, reverse-proxy, url-rewrite-module, server-core

I am trying to use IIS with Application Request Routing as a reverse proxy for an instance of Jenkins running on the same host. The host is running Windows Server 2016 (Server Core).

Jenkins is running on localhost:8080 while the default IIS site (which I am using as the reverse proxy site) is on 10.0.0.84:80
I have managed to get URL rewrite to work as per [this tutorial](https://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/using-jenkins-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-iis/) but it does not work with Jenkins' CSRF support and will report 403s due to the "Crumb" not being present.

I am assuming that I need some kind of outgoing rewrite rule to make this work properly. I have scoured the internet and haven't found anybody else who has got this working.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm in similar boat with TeamCity... IIS proxying Apache.

Comment: I never really got it working. I managed to track the issue to the fact that the CSRF check includes a URL embedded in a URL. When IIS parses the URL, it escapes it properly but passes it on unescaped.

So the url might be https://your.jenkins.io/blahblah?ref=http%3A%2F%2Fyour.jenkins.io%2Fcsrf

But if you ask for the "unescaped" version of the query URL, it just un-encodes the escaped version. This was about the point that I gave up, because wasn't familiar enough with the URL Rewrite rules and couldn't  debug them without a huge hassle.

If you do figure it out, I'd love to know.

Comment: Given our TeamCity server is on a private network I set `rest.cors.origins=*` in `C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\config\internal.properties`. This is a work-around to our problem, but more like shoving it under the carpet...